# RadialGradient for drawing Arc

Tags: android, canvas, gradient

How I can paint this gradient (radial gradient) in a arc?

I already have the arc drawed:

```
canvas.drawArc(new RectF(-radius, -radius, -radius, radius), angle(begin), angle(end) - angle(begin), false, myPaint);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following code will generate the radial gradient.

```
public RadialGradient createRadialGradient(RectF oval, int centertColor, int edgeColor) {
    return new RadialGradient(oval.centerX(), oval.centerY(), oval.width(), centerColor, edgeColor, TileMode.CLAMP);
}
```

Comment: :| I'm doing this but it's not working. If I put start = white ; end = black. All my arc is drawn in gray

Comment: Are you setting the gradient as a shader on myPaint?

Comment: yes, I am.         

RadialGradient gradient = new RadialGradient(rectF.centerX(), rectF.centerY(), rectF.width(), res.getColor(R.color.yellow), res.getColor(R.color.black), Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);

myPaint.setShader(gradient);

Comment: Try the radius as rectF.width()/2. Since we're giving the diameter here, it might be drawing only the top half which is the black color.

Comment: Now I can see something starting in white, but not  
enough

Comment: Well as you can see playing with the radius will give you different results. Try rectF.width()/4, or something else and see which result suits you more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78776/discussion-between-torque203-and-rguerra).

Answer (score 0):

add `android:centerColor` and use the same color of  `android:startColor` and also adjust android `android:gradientRadius`

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval" >
        <gradient android:type="radial" android:gradientRadius="600"

            android:startColor="#f3fdfdfd" android:centerColor="#f3fdfdfd" android:endColor="#ff0303" />


    </shape>
</item>
```